# Geometric Intuition behind Chebyshev's Inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality

I understand the proof behind this, and I've read a bunch of intuition behind it posts, but I don't think I completely understand what's happening. I also found a geometric intuition behind Markov's Inequality [post](https://lips.cs.princeton.edu/a-geometric-intuition-for-markovs-inequality/) and that made it easier to understand, so is there a geometric intuition behind this?

Markov's Inequality: $P(X \ge a) \le \frac{E[X]}{a}$ where $X > 0$

Chebyshev's Inequality: $P(|X - E[X]| \ge a) \le \frac{\sigma^{2}}{a^{2}}$

Comment: Suppose that you're distributing one unit of mass on the positive number line, but you need a certain proportion $P$ of the mass to lie at a value greater than $1$. How close can the center of mass of your distribution come to $0$? If you put the whole proportion $P$ at $1$ and leave the rest at $0$, your center of mass it at $P$. The Markov inequality says that you can't do better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember this and you won't forget...

[image]

That is, for $Z\geq 0,a>0,$ $${\large 1_{Z\geq a}}\leq Z/a.$$ Taking the expectation of both sides gives Markov's inequality:

$$P(Z\geq a)=E[{\large 1_{Z\geq a}}]\leq E[Z/a]=\frac{E[Z]}{a}.$$

---

A mere application of Markov's inequality gives Chebyshev's inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Proof)). But if you can't resist a pretty visual...

[image]

That is, for $a>0,$ $${\large 1_{|Z|\geq a}}\leq Z^2/a^2.$$ Letting $Z=X-E[X]$ and taking the expectation of both sides gives Chebyshev's inequality:

$$P(|X-E[X]|\geq a)=E[{\large 1_{|X-E[X]|\geq a}}]\leq E[(X-E[X])^2/a^2]=\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{a^2}.$$

Comment: How is $P(Z \geq a) = E[1_{Z \geq a}]$? Shouldn't $P(Z \geq a) = 1_{Z \geq a}$ since $P(Z \geq a) = 1$ if $Z \geq a$ and $= 0$ otherwise just like $1_{Z \geq a}$?

Comment: @IbrahimHasaan No, keep in mind $1_{Z\geq a}$ is itself a random variable (depending on random variable $Z$), so $P(Z\geq a)$ cannot be $1_{Z\geq a}.$ What you can say is that trivially, $$P(Z\geq a |1_{Z\geq a}=1)=1,P(Z\geq a|1_{Z\geq a}=0)=0.$$ As for the mean, use the definition: $$E[1_{Z\geq a}]=1\cdot P(Z\geq a)+0\cdot P(Z<a).$$

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are trying to construct a random variable $X$ with mean zero, such that the probability of $X$ falling at least $a$ units away from zero is at least $m$, but you want the variance of $X$ to be as small as possible.

The way you would do this is to put probability masses of $\frac m2$ at $+a$ and $-a$, with the remaining $(1-m)$ mass concentrated at zero.

Then $V(X)=a^2m$, and any other arrangement would move mass away from the center and give you a higher variance. Thus
$$\sigma^2 \geq a^2m $$
which gives
$$m = P(|X-E[X]| \geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$$